# How to get rid of fireflies coming from apartment windows?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I've tried different settings of clamping, sun/no sun, lamps, emission, higher samples, etc... but I can't seem to get rid of them. Not keen on blur nodes or similar since I need to see the inside of the apartments > people, furniture, etc... 
And I also need reflections from the windows so I don't want a hole instead of windows.

<s>Download Blend file here: http://we.tl/2oPC7y4zdc</s>

And please **don't** mark this as a *duplicate* cus I've tried finding answers here on blender.exchange, Blender Guru and YT without any luck as you can see.

*Note: I'm a total noob. Just started Blender about a month ago.*

See ref img > [image]

Comment: please consider uploading your file to a more permanent host like http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  . Files from wetransfer.com expire within a couple of weeks and then other users won't be able to inspect it.

Comment: are you sure it's not a [duplicate](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that what you describe are fireflies but noise and pixelation resulting from rendering at a low resolution with low samples.

This is a render form your original file
just 100 samples at 50% resolution.
:[image]

**EDIT**

Changing the glass of the windows to a node tree like this you can have transparency and reflections (look at the added emitter plane on the left).

Rendering with more samples at a higher resolution will give you a cleaner image.

[image]

[image]

For a deeper explanation on the nodes used please read [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles)

Note the change with more samples and a higher resolution:

[image]

(*click on the image to enlarge*)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a camera only glass shader?

Comment: The glass shader has issues with light sources going through it...

Comment: Right, but that's why you'd make it camera only. Like, that the _Is Camera Ray_ input and use it to drive a mix of glass and transparent shaders

Comment: @someonewithpc Thanks for your reply.
In the file I've attached, Yes, it was set to 100 but as I mentioned I tried with higher samples but stopped at 1500. I see you have 2000 samples but it's still kinda noisy in my opinion. If it would be a still frame I would just solve this in Photoshop with ease.
_My second question is: Will it look this noisy during animation as well?_ 
Or is it impossible to make it look smooth, since CEGATON writes that the Glass Shader has issues with light source going through?
I will also give it a try with _Is Camera Ray_ to see if that has any effect.

Comment: @cegaton So in your **experience** it's not possible to achieve a better result than what SOMEONEWITHPC rendered?

Comment: @MichaelHansen see edited answer

Comment: @cegaton Thanks. I will give it a try now right away.

Comment: @MichaelHansen Noise is less evident in animation (the history of film is full of noisy images) as you don't see each image in detail for a long time. What's crucial though for animation is to have a different noise seed. Plese read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/925/can-you-change-the-render-seed-for-each-frame-of-an-animation-in-cycles

Comment: @cegaton Excerpt from your link: "...This generates a different noise pattern for each frame."  
So I guess that would improve the noise. When I start animating I will definitely remember about the Seed option. 
I need to read more about it but your input has been of great help cus rendering an animation with 2k samples seems a lot in terms of rendering time.

Comment: @MichaelHansen look at any movie you like, if you pause it you'll see that most of the images are noisy... If you play back 24 noisy images per second you'll see that the noise is not that big an issue...

Comment: GOOD. CHEAP. FAST... you can only choose two...

Comment: Fireflies usually don't disappear if you increase the samples. I had similar problems and changing the "clamp indirect" settings and increasing the light bounces for translucent / diffuse did the trick for me. also check out this awesome article: [link](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/)