# Cycles: objects appearing in 'Render' render but not 'Animation' render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm not really that familiar with cycles textures, so there's probably something wrong there.

Anyway, my objects appear when I hit the 'render' button:

[image]

But not when I try the 'animation' render. All I get is my grid object and my lights.

I have another file with versions of the objects with the single basic node that appears when you first add a texture, and those will render in the animation render, but not the rest of them.

What am I doing wrong? Node setups are shown. File is here: [click](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=43213).
All the objects are on the same render layer, and they're all set to display in the render.

EDIT: 
No issue to speak of here. I just forgot that nothing is in the render area until frame 17... I'm silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scene renders fine.

You only see the background on because your text object is not in frame until frame 17...when it drops down.

[image]

Comment: As a side note. To avoid the fixed noise pattern when animating see this link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/925/can-you-change-the-render-seed-for-each-frame-of-an-animation-in-cycles

Comment: how embarrassing. that is exactly the case... I guess I was so irritated with it I just didn't think about it. Thanks