# Network Render for one image using tiles?

Tags: rendering, network

Hi fellas is there a way to use network render for one image? Mean like for anim when idle computer start to compute next image but using tiles so the idle computer will start the next tile.

I know its possible on one computer using CUDA CPU + GPU that idle HW start next one but is there a way to use second computer? I mean in Cycles for sure.

**I think there has to be a way because using SheepIt render farm You could divide every single image into multiple "instances" and these are rendered on different computers as far as I know.**

I dont want to combine two images with different seeds and half samples like its answered in many different questions but wonder if someone know the system used on the farm mentioned above.

Sincerely, Jan

*REM: If Im not mistaken V-Ray could be used like this? So Cycles?*

Comment: I think its _not_ a duplicate Duarte cause Im wondering if **someone knows how its done on SheepIt Farm** cause I dont want to combine two images with different seeds of sampling.

Comment: @JanMatys If you [animate the seed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/926/26640), you can use SheepIt to get multiple frames w/ different seeds, then combine as explained in the question linked above.

Comment: Hm, I think there is no need when using SheepIt to use multiple frames cause there is always someone with a DAMN fast computer ;). Im only asking cause maybe here is also someone who could solve it directly in Blender with some addon...